# About hadoop mrjob cannot mkdir

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, hdfs

I'm trying to run a mapreduce job.I set the output path as: /local/mypath/mr_reuslt But get:

```
SEVERE: Mkdirs failed to create: /local/mypath/mr_reuslt/_temporary
```

But I'm sure from my account I can do mkdir to hadoop.
If I manually do hadoop fs -mkdir /local/mypath/mr_reuslt/_temporary, it creates the folders.
There's no other exception message related with it.
I really don't think is a permission problem. When I explicitly call create file in the mk job, it gets created.
Could anyone please give me some suggestion about what's happening here?
Sorry, I have to mention that I was trying to invoke map reduce job from my java code.
I call:

```
ToolRunner.run(new Validation(), new String[]{...,...,...});
```

From my Java code.
Is that the problem?
May I ask is there any good way we can invoked mapreduce job from normal java code?

Here's my test code:

```
for(final ExecJob e: jobSet){
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            @Override
            public void run() {
                String inputPath = pathsForValidation.get(e);
                String outputPath = inputPath+validationExten;
                logger.log(LogLevel.INFO,"Should validate data in "+inputPath+", validation result in "+outputPath);
                try {
                    ToolRunner.run(new Validation(), new String[]{TransferToHadoopUtilities.hdfsPath,inputPath,outputPath});
                } catch (Exception e1) {
                    logger.log(LogLevel.ERROR,"Thread encountered exception:");
                    TransferToHadoopUtilities.logger.log(e1);
                }finally{
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
                }
            }
            
        });
        t.start();
    }
```

I just start this code in my Java program. Not do Hadoop jar.

But start as a Java application.

Comment: what user+group is hadop runing under?

Comment: I am not in the adm group, but I have very high permission from my account to make any dir or delete any.Thank you:)

Comment: You might have sufficient permissions, but the user that Hadoop is running under may not

Comment: I run it under the same account.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that Hadoop does not have the proper permissions to create that output directory. This can happen when running a job as a system user other than a Hadoop user.

I guess the easy way out is to create the output directory manually before running the job.

Comment: I tried to created the ouput manually, it still fail at _temporary creation.

Answer (score 0):

It's very likely this is because the user Hadoop job is running as doesn't have sufficient permission.

However, I would either get the output directory permissions changed or run the job as your user instead of doing anything manually before each run of the job.

Answer (score 0):

That's perhaps because the directory already exists. Depending on what you're trying to accomplish you could perhaps timestamp the directory. BTW make sure you cleanup as well.